# Adding & Removing additional class on my element tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning Angular.js and at first glimpse I thought it was easy. :P. But I'm stuck here. What I want is to add another class on my <.a>(anchor) tag.

My HTML Code:

```
<a href="#/services" title="Services" class="scroll">
<a href="#/portfolio" title="Portfolio" class="scroll">
```

Say when I click the service link it will add "enabled" class

```
<a href="#/services" title="Services" class="scroll enabled">
<a href="#/portfolio" title="Portfolio" class="scroll">
```

then if I clicked the portfolio link it will add "enabled" class also and will remove the enabled class from the services anchor tag

```
<a href="#/services" title="Services" class="scroll">
<a href="#/portfolio" title="Portfolio" class="scroll enabled">
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Read about ng-click and ng-class, and also does ng-class support ternary operator? Their docs doesn't say anything about that. [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm starting with Angular too, and in similar cases i'm using directives , check this out:

```
yourApp.directive('scroll', function () {        
    return {
    restrict : 'C',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind("click" , function(e){
                 $("a").removeClass("enabled"); // Here we need jQuery
                 element.addClass("enabled");
            });     
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Hurray , i found a solution without jQuery! `element`'s `click` handler now looks like this:

```
element.bind("click" , function(e){
   element.parent().find("a").removeClass("enabled"); // Vanilla jqLite!
   element.addClass("enabled");
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jw16wW

Comment: I like you're idea. But sorry for asking this. How do I apply this in my current code? I created a directives.js but its showing me an error " selectors not implemented "

Comment: @WonderingCoder my fault , `angular.element("a")` will not work , and " selectors not implemented " is actually the reason. So in this case it is rational to use jQuery , imho.

Comment: haha, thanks men!. you are my abba. :P. It's working now. Maybe we could exchange email/skype since your also starting to learn Angular. Is it okay?

Comment: @WonderingCoder great , no problem , my mail is my nickname at gmail

Comment: nice dude!. Thanks again for this perfect solution. Owe you two now. :))

Answer (score 7):

simply add this code inside your angular function to remove class

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(".yourClass")).removeClass("yourClass");
```

OR

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("#yourSelector")).removeClass("#yourSelector");
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

try it this way

```
    <a href="#/services" title="Services" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activeTab == 'services'}>
    <a href="#/portfolio" title="Portfolio" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activeTab == 'portfolio'}>

and in the app.js
inject the route service like this
    angular.module('myModel',[]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/services', {
                            templateUrl: 'my.tpl',
                            controller:,,myCtrl,
                            activeTab:  "services"
                        }). 
                       when('/portfolio', {
                            templateUrl: 'my2.tpl',
                            controller: myCtrl2,
                            activeTab:  "portfolio"
                        })
    });
```

"activeTab" is a self-defined variable , the ng-class will be shown rely on it.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. didn;t work. It doesn't add the class "enabled".